# Javascript - setting a property name using a variable that contains brackets

Tags: javascript, variables, properties, brackets

I have a form with some fields -

```
<input name=store[0] value="1">
<input name=store[1] value="2">
```

When a save button is clicked the script picks up all the fields to be sent to a `$.post()`

```
inputs.each(function() {    
    field = this.name;
    value = $(this).val();
    jsonString[field] = value;
)};

$.post("/someScript.php", {
    fields : jsonString
});
```

When that script receives the data it comes through as

```
[storeId[0] = 1
[storeId[1] = 2
```

Instead of (as I expected it to)

```
[storeId[0]] = 1
[storeId[1]] = 2
```

EDIT :

Ok so silly me -

```
jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonString);
```

This passed over easily and I wasn able to decode it on the other end.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Because it isn't JSON? It looks like you're trying to post the JS object. Try using `JSON.stringify` on the object before you post it.

Comment: Hmm - that doesn't seem to resolve it, but i'll keep playing around with it.

Comment: Please look at the actual request in the dev console. Does it contain the brackets? If yes, post the serverside code.